# Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 19 arguments

Tags: excel, nested-if

```
=(IF(or(E3="Kalyan",E3="Prescribe",E3="Ucook"),"Ram Varan",IF(E3="Mr.Cook",E3="Lifelong",E3="Kimatsu"),"Jay Kumar",IF(E3="Candes",E3="Aahar"),"Aanirudh",IF(E3="Anticware",E3="Suryakraft"),"pradeep",IF(E3="Pexpo",E3="Big plastic"),"Ashish",IF(E3="Cello",E3="Crompton"),"Bhupender",IF(E3="Kirvan"),"Rakesh",IF(E3="Rajkamal"),"Nilesh",IF(E3="Kanak Bandhan"),"Mayank",IF(E3="Rajkamal")"Abhishek",IF(E3="Pigeon"),"Shantanu",IF(E3="Prestige"),"Gaurav",IF(E3="Avais"),"Pushp"))
```

How do I solve this error

Comment: Post few sample data and desired output mentioning your version of excel. There may be updated easier formula for you. Only seeing this formula we can suggest you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(E3="Kalyan",E3="Prescribe",E3="Ucook"),"Ram Varan",
IF(OR(E3="Mr.Cook",E3="Lifelong",E3="Kimatsu"),"Jay Kumar",
IF(OR(E3="Candes",E3="Aahar"),"Aanirudh",
IF(OR(E3="Anticware",E3="Suryakraft"),"pradeep",
IF(OR(E3="Pexpo",E3="Big plastic"),"Ashish",
IF(OR(E3="Cello",E3="Crompton"),"Bhupender",
IF(E3="Kirvan","Rakesh",
IF(E3="Rajkamal","Nilesh",
IF(E3="Kanak Bandhan","Mayank",
IF(OR(E3="Rajkamal","Abhishek"),
IF(E3="Pigeon","Shantanu",
IF(E3="Prestige","Gaurav",
IF(E3="Avais","Pushp","")))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=(IF(OR(E3="Kalyan",E3="Prescribe",E3="Ucook"),
     "Ram Varan",
     IF(OR(E3="Mr.Cook",E3="Lifelong",E3="Kimatsu"),
        "Jay Kumar",
        IF(OR(E3="Candes",E3="Aahar"),
           "Aanirudh",
           IF(OR(E3="Anticware",E3="Suryakraft"),
              "pradeep",
              IF(OR(E3="Pexpo",E3="Big plastic"),
                 "Ashish",
                 IF(OR(E3="Cello",E3="Crompton"),
                    "Bhupender",
                    IF(E3="Kirvan",
                       "Rakesh",
                       IF(E3="Rajkamal",
                          "Nilesh",
                          IF(E3="Kanak Bandhan",
                             "Mayank",
                             IF(E3="Rajkamal",
                                "Abhishek",
                                IF(E3="Pigeon",
                                   "Shantanu",
                                   IF(E3="Prestige",
                                      "Gaurav",
                                      IF(E3="Avais",
                                      "Pushp"))))))))))))))
```

The problem here is not how to give you the solution, but to explain you how to obtain it.
As you can see, I have created indenting for the different levels inside your if-loop. Next to that, there were also some issues with the brackets (like `IF(E3="Kirvan")`, the closing bracket should not be there). However, every `=OR()` should be closed by a bracket.
I would advise you to use a text editor (like Notepad++ in this case), which shows the correspondence between brackets (while putting the cursor at one bracket, it gets shown in red and the corresponding bracket (if present) too, this allows you to check if the correspondence between the brackets is complete and correct, as you can see in the screenshot (the green rectangles show two corresponding brackets:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example of a different approach:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K3,$D$2:$E$22,2,0),"Not in list")
```

[image]

I prefer this, as I avoid nesting more that 3 or 4 if() as it just gets too complicated.

Having a list is easier to control and you will note that you have "Rajkamal" with two different results for you to check.